# PostgreSQL: Trunc datetime column and update

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL datatable  with a datetime column and a value which holds integer values. The values in the datetime column include seconds. Now I wanna round it off so it only has date-hours-minutes. I know I can use trunc() to round it to only minutes.
But how can I update all rows with the truncated datetime? I have this to read the two columns and trunc the ‘datumtijd’ column to whole minutes. But how can I update the existing values in the column with the truncated values?

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('minute',datumtijd)  AS dt, waarde FROM datagas
```

I thought this would work to trunc my ‘datumtijd’ column, but it doesn’t change my values?! :

```
update test set datumtijd=(SELECT DATE_TRUNC('minute', datumtijd));
```

Thnx in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with the folowing:

```
update datagas set datumtijd = date_trunc('minute', datumtijd) where datumtijd is not null;
```